# How can I silently authenticate a user on a separate website when they're already logged-in on the central OAuth2 / OIDC site?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

- I have developed my own OAuth2 / OIDC web-application using IdentityServer4 which works fine. This is at https://myauthservice.com
- I then have a separate website which is a registered client of my IdentityServer4 service which is located at https://mywebsite.com.
- Both websites are made using ASP.NET Core 2.1.
- The `/` (homepage) of https://mywebsite.com has no authorization rules applied to it.

  - However if a user is already logged-in `if( this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated )` then they're redirected to their account page (`/account`) which does have an authorization rule, if the user is not authorized (e.g. because they're unauthenticated) they're redirected to https://myauthservice.com's login page with a `returnURL` set.
  - The homepage also has a HTML `<a href="/account">Login to your account</a>` link which when clicked causes the login process described above to happen.

The problem is when a visitor has already logged-in to https://myauthservice.com but has not already visited https://mywebsite.com then they get redirected to https://myauthservice.com's login page, which sees they're already authenticated there (by checking the `myauthservice.com` cookies) and redirects them back to https://mywebsite.com with the right `access_token`.

I want to eliminate that step, so that users on https://mywebsite.com won't see the "Login to your account" page nor suffer two browser redirects if they're already logged-in to https://myauthservice.com - but https://mywebsite.com won't have the user's `access_token` so what's the solution?

I understand I could have a hidden `<iframe>` on https://mywebsite.com's homepage `/` that points to https://myauthservice.com's login page (with `returnURL` set) which would return the `access_token` correctly and then a client-side script would detect it and automatically redirect the user to the `/account` page, but this also feels like a hack.

Another option is to modify the login process on https://myauthservice.com to include a hidden *reverse* `<iframe>` that causes the browser to send the `access_token` to *all* websites I trust (not just https://mywebsite.com) to get the right cookies beforehand, so when they eventually do visit https://mywebsite.com they'll already have the auth cookie present and be redirected to `/account` on the first request.

What guidance from the IdentityServer4 team or OAuth2/OIDC community exists for this scenario?

Update: I now realise I'm basically asking how to implement true single-sign-on using IdentityServer4. StackExchange solved this problem back in 2010: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/11/global-network-auto-login/ - I need to see how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to stick to using standard OpenID Connect stuff, you can use a prompt=none authorize request which will tell you if they’re already authenticated or not. This can work on client side (iframe) or server side redirect  (no ui shown so user will be unaware). If you receive an error code of login_required you know to then initiate the regular sign in flow, otherwise you’ll receive the ID and access token and you can perform a local login as normal.

In practice it works well and isn’t a hack at all as this approach is part of the OIDC session management spec.